# How to configure DHCP given Oracle instructions don't work?

Tags: networking, dhcp, solaris

I'm trying to enable DHCP on an Solaris 11 machine. My DHCP server is a m0n0wall, and it provides all network configuration information except the local broadcast address (limitation in m0n0wall).

For my installation, DNS/name resolution fails. It appears DHCP is not configured correctly since the information is provided with DHCP:

```
qotom-solaris11:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: getaddrinfo: temporary name resolution failure
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

I've repeatedly followed Oracles instructions to reset the machine found [How to Enable a DHCP Client](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1453/dhcp-config-67.html). The process uses `sysconfig configure` and it setups the networking stack, adds the root password, adds users, sets the timezone, etc. Its basically a machine reset.

How do I enable DHCP given Oracle instructions don't work?

Related, resetting an entire machine seems kind of extreme. Why does Oracle tell people to reset their entire machine?

---

***EDIT***

```
$ sudo ifconfig net0
net0: flags=100001004843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DHCP,IPv4,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 172.16.4.21 netmask ffff0000 broadcast 172.16.255.255
        ether 52:54:0:4:42:a3
```

And:

```
$ sudo netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              172.16.1.1           UG        1          0 net0      
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        3        998 lo0       
172.16.0.0           172.16.4.21          U         3        385 net0      

Routing Table: IPv6
  Destination/Mask            Gateway                   Flags Ref   Use    If   
--------------------------- --------------------------- ----- --- ------- ----- 
::1                         ::1                         UH      2     686 lo0   
fe80::/10                   fe80::5054:ff:fe04:42a3     U       2       0 net0
```

And:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf

#
# _AUTOGENERATED_FROM_SMF_V1_
#
# WARNING: THIS FILE GENERATED FROM SMF DATA.
#   DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.  EDITS WILL BE LOST.
# See resolv.conf(4) for details.

domain  home.pvt
```

The following is from an observer machine on the same subnet running `dhcpdump`. It captured the traffic between the DHCP server and the Solaris host:

```
$ sudo dhcpdump -i eth0
  TIME: 2016-08-25 21:14:32.717
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (52:54:0:4:42:a3) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: ef048b4a
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 52:54:00:04:42:a3:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         3 (DHCPREQUEST)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        172.16.4.21
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      -1 ()
OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 1472
OPTION:  60 ( 10) Vendor class identifier   SUNW.i86pc
OPTION:  55 (  6) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                          3 (Routers)
                         12 (Host name)
                         15 (Domainname)
                         28 (Broadcast address)
                         43 (Vendor specific info)
```

---

Here's some `dmesg` information. It may (or may not) be relevant.

```
qotom-solaris11:~$ dmesg | egrep -i '(dhcp|error)'
Aug 25 20:07:45 qotom-solaris11 /sbin/dhcpagent[372]: [ID 778557 daemon.warning] configure_v4_lease: no IP broadcast specified for net0, making best guess
Aug 25 20:08:05 qotom-solaris11 auditd[522]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:05 qotom-solaris11 auditd[721]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:06 qotom-solaris11 auditd[522]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:06 qotom-solaris11 auditd[721]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:07 qotom-solaris11 auditd[522]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:07 qotom-solaris11 auditd[721]: [ID 956865 daemon.error] getaddrinfo(qotom-solaris11) failed[temporary name resolution failure].
Aug 25 20:08:08 qotom-solaris11 auditd[522]: [ID 994446 daemon.error] mapping qotom-solaris11 to fe80::5054:ff:fe04:42a3.
Aug 25 20:08:08 qotom-solaris11 auditd[721]: [ID 994446 daemon.error] mapping qotom-solaris11 to fe80::5054:ff:fe04:42a3.
Aug 25 20:15:16 qotom-solaris11 rpcbind: [ID 564983 daemon.error] rpcbind terminating on signal.
Aug 25 20:17:20 qotom-solaris11 /sbin/dhcpagent[372]: [ID 778557 daemon.warning] configure_v4_lease: no IP broadcast specified for net0, making best guess
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and include the networking setup of the client?  Provide the response from `ifconfig` `netstat -rn` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and the dhcp scope and options the dhcp server is supposed to give out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `/etc/default/dhcpagent` was corrupt. I'm guessing it became corrupt during one of the many power problems we experience at the house. Gadgets of value are surge protected, but most lack an active UPS. The Solaris test machine is not a priority, so it lacks the UPS.

Copying `/etc/default/dhcpagent` from a working Solaris 11 test machine and rebooting resolved the issue (shown below). So much for that reset Oracle kept telling me to perform...

```
$ cat /etc/default/dhcpagent
#
# Copyright (c) 1999, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#

#
# This file contains tunable parameters for dhcpagent(1M).
#

# All parameters can be tuned for a specific interface by prepending
# the interface name to the parameter name.  For example, to make
# VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY happen on all interfaces except hme0, specify:
#
# hme0.VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=no
# VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=yes
#
# An interface name alone specifies IPv4 DHCP.  For DHCPv6, append ".v6".
# Some examples:
#
# hme0.VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=no           specify hme0 v4 behavior
# hme0.v6.VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=no        specify hme0 v6 behavior
# VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=no                match all v4 interfaces
# .v6.VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=no            match all v6 interfaces

# By default, when the DHCP agent is sent a SIGTERM (typically when
# the system is shut down), all managed addresses are dropped rather
# than released.  Dropping an address does not notify the DHCP server
# that the address is no longer in use, leaving it possibly available
# for subsequent use by the same client.  If DHCP is later restarted
# on the interface, the client will ask the server if it can continue
# to use the address.  If the server either grants the request, or
# does not answer (and the lease has not yet expired), then the client
# will use the original address.
#
# Similarly, when the system is suspended and then woken up or when
# the link status transitions from down to up, DHCP will ask the server
# to continue to use the managed address, in case the lease has changed.
#
# By uncommenting the following parameter-value pairs, all managed
# addresses are released on SIGTERM instead, and any that may have been
# saved but cannot be verified will not be used.  When SIGTERM is
# received, the DHCP server is notified that the address is available
# for use, and the address will not be saved for a later restart.  If
# DHCP receives SIGTHAW or a link-up event, DHCP will attempt to verify
# the previous lease, but if unable to do so, it will not attempt to
# use that lease.  This behavior is often preferred for roaming systems.
#
# VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=yes
# .v6.VERIFIED_LEASE_ONLY=yes

# By default, the DHCP agent waits 3 seconds to collect OFFER
# responses to a DISCOVER.  If it receives no OFFERs in this time, it
# then waits for another 3 seconds, and so forth.  To change this
# behavior, set and uncomment the following parameter-value pair.
# Note: this does not control the retransmission strategy for
# DISCOVERs, which is formally specified in RFC 2131.  This parameter
# is specified in seconds.
#
# OFFER_WAIT=

# By default, the DHCP agent does not send out a client identifier
# (and hence, the chaddr field is used by the DHCP server as the
# client identifier.)  To make the DHCP agent send a client
# identifier, set and uncomment the following parameter-value pair.
# Note that by default this is treated as an NVT ASCII string.  To
# specify a binary value, prepend "0x" to a sequence of hexadecimal
# digits (for example, the value 0xAABBCC11 would set the client
# identifier to the 4-byte binary sequence 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC 0x11).
#
# CLIENT_ID=

# By default, a parameter request list requesting a subnet mask (1),
# router (3), DNS server (6), hostname (12), DNS domain (15), broadcast
# address (28), and encapsulated vendor options (43), is sent to the DHCP
# server when the DHCP agent sends requests.  However, if desired, this
# can be changed by altering the following parameter-value pair.  The
# numbers correspond to the values defined in the IANA bootp-dhcp-parameters
# registry at the time of this writing.  Site and standard option names from
# /etc/dhcp/inittab are also accepted.
#
PARAM_REQUEST_LIST=1,3,6,12,15,28,43

# The default DHCPv6 parameter request list has preference (7), unicast (12),
# DNS addresses (23), DNS search list (24), NIS addresses (27), and
# NIS domain (29).  This may be changed by altering the following parameter-
# value pair.  The numbers correspond to the values defined in the IANA
# dhcpv6-parameters registry at the time of this writing.  Site and standard
# option names from /etc/dhcp/inittab6 are also accepted.
.v6.PARAM_REQUEST_LIST=7,12,23,24,27,29

# The parameter ignore list allows you to instruct the DHCP client to discard
# optional parameters received from the DHCP server.  The format is the same
# as the request list above.  When discarded, a parameter will not be acted
# on by the DHCP client or returned to users via the dhcpinfo(1) command.
PARAM_IGNORE_LIST=
.v6.PARAM_IGNORE_LIST=
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Troubleshooting Solaris DHCP Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5529/6jehkcs8f/index.html), they detail the procedure as this:

```
 # pkill -x dhcpagent
 # /sbin/dhcpagent -d1 -f &
 # ifconfig net0 dhcp start
```

Comment: Thanks. The cited link results in *"We're sorry, the page you requested was not found"*. I'm not real impressed with Solaris and its documentation...

Comment: Sorry, pasted link without last letter! Now I've corrected the link for completitude.